# What is the use of 'as_supervised' boolean expression while loading a Tensorflow Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, dataset

Let's say that I'm trying to import the *imdb_reviews* dataset from **tensorflow_datasets** using the following:

```
imdb, info = tfds.load("imdb_reviews", with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
```

Now in this, I tried to find in the documentation about the *as_supervised* boolean but didn't understand. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If as_supervised, the resulting Dataset will be a collection of tuples containing a label for each input.

("a horrible thing",  "bad"),
("a wonderful thing", "good"),
("woe be me",         "bad")…